# Undefined web3.eth.getAccounts() in React Native, metamask authentication

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, web3js, metamask

I want to authenticate the user by his Metamask wallet. I am using [web3 package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/web3) in order to interact with the blocks and sign transactions. When I try to get the user accounts I get an empty result:

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3(
  new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://api.avax.network/ext/bc/C/rpc')
);
const addresses = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
```

I suppose that I need to request the accounts like this `await window.ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts'});` but it doesn't exist `window` mobile app.

I guess in a normal flow the user hit the auth button and will be redirected to Metamask wallet to authorize the app, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out a solution, I do not know if is the best way to do it.

In order to interact with the blocks and sign transactions the users authenticate their MetaMask wallet through [WalletConnect](https://walletconnect.com/) service.

After the user is authenticated I can use the connector to create a provider in order to use it with *ethers.js* lib (Using web3.js the connection with RPC failed, I decided to use ethers instead):

```
const walletConnectProvider = new WalletConnectProvider({
    rpc: {
        43114: RPC 
    },
    chainId: 43114,
    connector: this.connector,
    qrcode: false
})
let wp = await walletConnectProvider.enable();
if(wp){
    this.provider = new providers.Web3Provider(walletConnectProvider);
}


const signer = this.provider.getSigner();
const contract = new Contract(GAMESESSION_ADDRESS, GameSession.abi, signer);
....
```

It is a little tricky but WalletConnect works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, but you also need to connect to MetaMask, not your own RPC. Here is your fixed code:

```js
import detectEthereumProvider from '@metamask/detect-provider';

const web3 = await detectEthereumProvider(); // Use Metamask-injected web3
await web3.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts'});
const addresses = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
```

Comment: `Web3.givenProvider` is null and `TypeError: web3.request is not a function.`.

Comment: `Web3.givenProvider` shouldn't be null, chances are that's a bug. `web3.request` is my bad - it's actually `web3.currentProvider.sendAsync` I'll edit my answer to something that should hopefully work better.

Comment: `detectEthereumProvider()` returns `TypeError: window.addEventListener is not a function. (In 'window.addEventListener('ethereum#initialized', handleEthereum, { once: true })', 'window.addEventListener' is undefined)`. I guess in some how I need to redirect the user tu metamask app in order to request the accounts.

Comment: Also `@metamask/detect-provider` package is only for web browsers.

Comment: Wait... how are you expecting to sign a transaction in MetaMask outside of a browser?

Comment: Yes, I want to use MetaMask for sign transactions inside a mobile app

Comment: You will probably need to use another ethereum provider then. Metamask only works for websites.

Comment: Any idea of whitch provider? I can't find any easy solution

Comment: You should probably use an ethers jsonrpc provider, along with an ethers Wallet signer.